# Login Page Hash issue UPDATE

Tags: hash, authentication, passwords

I am having a issue with my login page reading a function to login

on my register page which I'm proud to say works perfect

this is my password hash code

```
  $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

my login page has 2 fields

email &
password

I have re cleaned my code and solved the issue some what

functions are working

when I enter email and password it triggers

Warning! Email or Password Incorrect

plus an error at the top

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\CMS\functions\functions.php on line 249

this is line 249
$db_password = $row['password'];

```
/* Validate Login */


function validate_login()
{
    $errors = [];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        $email = clean($_POST['email']);
        $password = clean($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($email)) {

            $errors[] = "Email Required";
        }

        if (empty($password)) {

            $errors[] = "Password Required";
        }

        if (! empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo validation_errors($error);
            }
        } else {

            if (login_user($email, $password)) {

                redirect("../account/profile.php");
            } else {

                echo validation_errors("Email or Password Incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
} // End Function





/* User Login */

function login_user($email, $password)
{
    $sql = "SELECT user_pwd, uid FROM userss WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "'";

    $result = query($sql);
    if (row_count($result) == 1) {

        $row = fetch_array($result);
        $db_password = $row['password'];

        if (hash_algos($password) == $db_password) {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
}// End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just figured out the issue

```
if (hash_algos($password) == $db_password) {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
```

changed it to this

```
if(password_verify($password, $db_password)){

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a closing bracket for your `validate_login()` function so it is defining the `login_user()` function only after the first function is called. Therefore as you progress through your `validate_login()` function you call the `login_user()` function before it is created since it is created after the if statement completes.